# C# Как просканировать ip адреса другого диапазона

Tags: c#, ip, lan

Здравствуйте! Появилась необходимость сканировать ip адреса другого диапазона. Возможно я немного не правильно выражаюсь. Попробую объяснить. 
На работе имеется 5 роутеров, в каждом торчит usb свисток "Ёты". (Сделано так по причине того что кабельный интернет запрещен на территории) На каждом роутере по 10+ человек. Все роутеры в одной сети с ip 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.2 и т.д. Нашел с десяток примеров рабочих локальных сканеров по ip и все бы ни чего. Но... Собственно проблема. Программа сканирует ip адреса только с тем же адресом что и роутер. К примеру, если роутер 192.168.3.3, то с 192.168.1.1 проверить компьютер на присутствие я уже не могу. Приходится переключаться на другой роутер и там уже проверять. Смысл программы: Запомнить все доступные компьютеры в сети и периодически их проверять на доступность. Каждый раз менять себе ip и проделывать это руками жутко неудобно... Надеюсь на вашу помощь или совет!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск программ -- оффтопик на сайте.

Comment: Можно попробовать свести вопрос к сисадминскому -- о том, чтобы расположить все роутеры в одну сеть - 10.0.x.1 с маской 255.255.0.0, но если я правильно понимаю ситуацию, то этого делать нельзя, а нужна именно программа.

Comment: A K. Ни кто и не просит искать программы вы что! Мне нужен пример кода работы подобной программы

Comment: Я перечитал трижды вопрос и до сих пор не вижу ни намека на написание программы. Может быть между строк где-то и видно стремление 'напишите за меня', ее более.

Answer (score 1):

Перенастроить роутеры. Так, чтобы все они были в одной подсети, а диапазоны выделения их DHCP не пересекались.

Альтернативный вариант - на сетевом интерфейсе сканирующего компьютера настроить несколько IP, по одному из каждой подсети.